# React Native: Unable To Sign Into my App- Error in fetching sourceURL

Tags: localhost, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I am unable to sign into my app on my iOS simulator on my computer or iPhone 7 (I am able to load expo and get to my sign in/register screen). It was working fine a couple days ago and today it stopped.. I have not touched any code that relates to the error I am getting. On the simulator I went to localhost:19001 and it says that React Native packager is running.

Here is the error I get in terminal:

error in fetching

> {"line":22374,"column":29,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:19001/node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=expo/tools/hashAssetFiles"}

Any advice or help would be great appreciated, I am eager to work on my project again.

Comment: You should try creating a new project and trying if a new project throws the same error or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are running your APP on `localhost`, try to change the server host from to `localhost` to the IP which you are using.